# What is the normalization factor in np.fft.irfft()?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm using `np.fft.irfft()` as part of a program to calculate the Wigner distribution. Since I don't want the normalized version of the fft, I need the normalization factor to "undo" the normalization.

**What is the normalization factor for np.fft.irfft()?**

Comment: If your answer isn't here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft, you might need to look at the source code, or devise some test cases.

Comment: The inverse FFT should have a 1/N term in it, which it does and `x == rfft(irfft(x))`. When you do the forward FFT you get an expected DC term that is the sum of the inputs,  and if the inverse brings you back to the original, then there must only be a 1/N "normalisation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the norm of `numpy.fft.irfft` is 1 over array length. To see that consider the following program:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
x = np.fft.irfft(t)

print  "Array length: ", len(t), "\t 1/n: ", 1.0/float(len(t)), "\t max x val: ", max(x)


x1 = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

t1 = np.fft.rfft(x1)

print  "Array length: ", len(t1), "\t 1/n: ", 1.0/float(len(t1)), "\t max t1 val: ", max(t1)
```

This outputs:

```
Array length:  128   1/n:  0.0078125     max x val:  0.00787401574803
Array length:  65    1/n:  0.0153846153846   max t1 val:  (1+0j)
```

From this I believe that the norm of the irfft is 1/n and from rfft it is 1. This would be in accordance with this [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) (see Implementation details).

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at the sum of `x` rather than the maximum value?